# Subdivide only adding vertices, wont subdivide faces

Tags: vertices

I am trying to use the subdivide tool, but when I do it only works on certain faces.  The next time I try to subdivide a face, it only adds vertices to the edge.

Comment: Can you share an image

Comment: It's most likely that the faces which you are trying to subdivide are Ngons (which have > 4 vertices). To subdivide cleanly try editing topology with joining adjacent vertices to return to quads.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I think you may be referring to the Loop Cut tool.
You press Ctrl+R to use the Loop Cut tool.

To subdivide a certain face, select the face in Edit mode and press W and select Subdivide. Then in the Toolshelf in the lower left Last Operator panel on the screen you can change the number of subdivisions. The maximum is 10 but if you need more you will have to subdivide again or you can type value manually.

Comment: Note that *Subdivide* won't split face if the latter is Ngon; it will only split the edges.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably faces in your model that contain more than 4 vertices. Because in that case it will subdivide the edges of that face only.